# How to run a .net application which uses sql , on two or three or multiple computers?

Tags: .net, system

I have a simple .net windows form which inserts user input into sql database.
Now i want to run sql server only on one system and connect the other three systems to the main system on which sql is installed and then run the application on all the three client machines. From all the 3 client machines the data (user input) would be inserted into the sql database?

Please guide me how to deploy this? I am a beginner in SQL. So, please if anybody can , then do mention the urls of websites also where i can find more information about this task.

i guess, do i have to make an exe file of my windows form and install it on all client machines and server as well?
after that how do i connect the client machines with the sql database on the server machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to it.

**Design**

- Your SQL Server will be installed on
  a single machine. This machine should
  be accessible via the other machines.
- Your application (Windows/Web) will use a connection string to connect to the SQL Server

Implementation
 - You can create an application (Windows/Web) and deploy it to all client machines. In the application settings, you can mention the SQL Server instance/credentials as per the connection string.

Comment: thanks a lot joshi sir, i would have to install the windows application on all the client systems.ok i would do that.so the client machines should be in LAN with the server? then only they would be able to connect to the sql on the server machine. am i right sir? also, when i want to see or verify in sql server express that whether the clients are connected or not, then how would i do that?

Comment: Yes. You would need to install the Windows App on all the client systems and they should be in LAN with the server.

Comment: Assuming your application is using some tables form the SQL Server database somehow, When you run the application on the client and it works - that means you are able to access the SQL Server. Alternately, you can launch SQL Management Studio from the client and type the server name to see if the connection is good.